# Can't save alarm, iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, alarm, clock

My iPhone 4s has recently deleted all my alarms and now I can't create any new ones.

- Open Clock
- Tap Alarm. Screen shows "No Alarms"
- Tap "+"
- Choose: Time: 11:00PM, Repeat: Never, Label: Alarm, Sound: Radar, Snooze: Yes
- Tap Save
- Screen goes back to show "No Alarms"

[image]
[image]

Specs:

- iPhone 4s
- iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
- Capacity 12.7Gb
- Available 633Mb

What I've tried:

- Turning it off and on again
- Hard reset

Answer (score 1):

That's very strange. The only thing that I can think a bug in the version of iOS that your iPhone 4S is running. So try a software update and if iOS 8.4.1 doesn't solve your problem, then hopefully iOS 9 will when it comes out in a few weeks.

If you don't wish to update your iPhone now, you could try to backup your iPhone and all apps (make sure to check "Encrypt Backup") and then wipe your iPhone and restore the backup. This, however, is a lot more tedious than just updating it.

So you should probably update it and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange. I can made it with my 4s. The version is 8.4.1(12H321). You may upgrade your iPhone to this version or the newest version to have a try. If it still does't work. You'd better test your phone at Apple Help Center.